# SSIS Excel Source failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C with 64BitRuntime set to FALSE

Tags: excel, import, ssis

I'm getting an error in SSIS as specified in the title when trying to import a certain Excel file.

Other Excel files import just fine.  Changing the 64BitRuntime property doesn't help.  I don't see anything unusual about this Excel file, have opened it and saved it just to see if that helped.

The Source task can preview the data in the spreadsheet, so it's not really a connection issue like the error states.

I've tried everything on the first 3 pages of Google hits.  Does anyone have any other ideas?

Here's the relevant part of the event log.  Everything before this looks good, but this is where things go wrong.

thanks in advance, and the file is definitely closed.

> BE2-248122A13220},2/17/2017 4:27:25 PM,2/17/2017 4:27:25 PM,0,0x,ExternalRequest_pre: The object is ready to make the following external request: 'ICommandWithParameters::GetParameterInfo'.
>   Diagnostic,XXXXX,"Excel Source" (12),{0000000C-0000-0000-0000-000000000000},{EA4F85BF-9B5E-4993-8BE2-248122A13220},2/17/2017 4:27:25 PM,2/17/2017 4:27:25 PM,0,0x,ExternalRequest_post: 'ICommandWithParameters::GetParameterInfo succeeded'. The external request has completed.
>   Diagnostic,XXXXX,XXXXX,{AFB678B6-C0C9-476B-A5DE-58FE89E42FA3},{EA4F85BF-9B5E-4993-8BE2-248122A13220},2/17/2017 4:27:25 PM,2/17/2017 4:27:25 PM,0,,ExternalRequest_pre: The object is ready to make the following external request: 'IDataInitialize::GetDataSource(NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, ConnectionString: Data Source=XXXXX;Initial Catalog=XXXXX;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;,...)'.
>   Diagnostic,XXXXX,XXXXX,{AFB678B6-C0C9-476B-A5DE-58FE89E42FA3},{EA4F85BF-9B5E-4993-8BE2-248122A13220},2/17/2017 4:27:25 PM,2/17/2017 4:27:25 PM,0,,ExternalRequest_post: 'IDataInitialize::GetDataSource succeeded'. The external request has completed.
>   Diagnostic,XXXXX,XXXXX,{AFB678B6-C0C9-476B-A5DE-58FE89E42FA3},{EA4F85BF-9B5E-4993-8BE2-248122A13220},2/17/2017 4:27:25 PM,2/17/2017 4:27:25 PM,0,,ExternalRequest_pre: The object is ready to make the following external request: 'IDBInitialize::Initialize'.
>   Diagnostic,XXXXX,XXXXX,{AFB678B6-C0C9-476B-A5DE-58FE89E42FA3},{EA4F85BF-9B5E-4993-8BE2-248122A13220},2/17/2017 4:27:25 PM,2/17/2017 4:27:25 PM,0,,ExternalRequest_post: 'IDBInitialize::Initialize failed'. The external request has completed.
>   OnError,XXXXX,EC Imports,{2FC1DE9B-4537-4046-AAC7-A0E535FC8577},{EA4F85BF-9B5E-4993-8BE2-248122A13220},2/17/2017 4:27:25 PM,2/17/2017 4:27:25 PM,-1071611876,0x,SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "XXXXX" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.

OnError,XXXXX,EC Imports,{2FC1DE9B-4537-4046-AAC7-A0E535FC8577},{EA4F85BF-9B5E-4993-8BE2-248122A13220},2/17/2017 4:27:25 PM,2/17/2017 4:27:25 PM,-1073450985,0x,OLE DB Destination failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.

Comment: Can you please post the rest of the errors in the log in their entirety?  Also, just off the top of my head, please make sure the file is not open in excel at the time that you are trying to run the package

Comment: Is it an xlsx file? Some applications export corrupt versions of these files that don't open in SSIS. What happens if you open the file in excel and resave it - does SSIS open it then?

Comment: It is an xlsx, and I tried opening and resaving several times before I posted, tried making a copy and using that, no luck.  Thanks though.